# How do I generate my linear transformation matrix in this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be the linear transformation of space of polynomials $P^3$ given by

$$T(a + bx + cx^2) = a + b(x + 1) + c(x + 1)^2$$

Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: Please don't demand anything of us.  By the way, if this is a homework problem, label it as such.  (People will still help you out.)

Comment: Do you know how to write down the matrix for this transformation in the monomial basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$?

Comment: It should be $P^2$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, we use the notation that $P^3$ represents all polynomials of degree less than 3. It's a bit non-intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: $a+bx+cx^2$ is equivalent to the vector $[a,b,c]^{T}$. Expanding the RHS
\begin{align}
T=(a+b+c)+(b+2c)x+cx^2
\end{align}
In terms of matrices, $T$ should be equivalent to
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b+c \\ b+2c \\ c
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Now try to find the eigenvectors.